# Actionbar with customView has extra padding that cannot be removed

Tags: android

Having trouble getting an ActionBar to display icons with proper styling.

My customer wants an ActionBar that has specific icons with varying shades of transparency. If I simply place the icons into an XML file in res/menu, then I have no way to get the icons to lie adjacent to each other and the backgrounds of each icon result in vertical gaps like so:

[image]

### res/menu/global_nav.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_main_menu"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/nav_menu_main"/>  

<item
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_people"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/nav_menu_login"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/location"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_location"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/nav_menu_location"/>
```

etc, etc.

So, I created a customView and simply placed the same icons within a RelativeLayout. That makes the icons line up better and doesn't leave the gaps between icons. I can style it easier, even though I lose the ability to use menus as above. However, it leaves a gap at the bottom of the row of icons above the PagerTitleStrip. The UX image people left the search icon with full transparency around the icon but all other have some light color which makes the extra padding below the icons very noticeable. Without the slight transparency around them one would probably never notice, but my customer wants that padding gone.

[image]

### res/layout/global_nav_custom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/att_blue"
android:paddingBottom="-54dp"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_main_menu" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_search" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/search"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_message" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/message"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_cart" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/location"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/cart"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_location" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/location"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_people" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/menu"
    android:layout_marginLeft="364dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menu"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### Java code

```
    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View customView = li.inflate(R.layout.global_nav_custom, null);


    bar.setCustomView(customView);
```

So, my question is A) how can I style the ActionBar to either use the standard  style XML as menu but remove the vertical gaps.  Or B) with a customView solution, I get a 4+ pixel gap at the bottom.

By the way, ActionBarSherlock is NOT an option as the company wants no 3rd party libraries

Comment: "the company wants no 3rd party libraries" Wow... So they prefer to implement their own, likely buggy code rather than use well proven libraries. With all the fantastic open source libraries available, I feel sorry for you...

Comment: tell me about it....probably the most dysfunctional shop ever

Answer (score 2):

**Using standard action buttons**

You can achieve this with standard action buttons by using a custom theme for your app.
Note: for this to work, your icons must be **32dp** or less

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarSize">32dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionButton" parent="android:Widget.ActionButton">
        <item name="android:paddingStart">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingEnd">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

[image]

Don't forget to edit your AndroidManifest to set the theme of your activity/application ;)

---

**Using actionLayout**

Another way is to specify an `actionLayout` for each of your action item. This way you can keep your icon anyway you want, and keep the action bar size to **48dp**.

The downside is you have to handle the menu item as a **button** rather than a menu item, by using a `OnClickListener` or using the `onClick` attribute of your **`View`**. The `onClick` attribute of the **`MenuItem`** will not work.

You should also probably display the menu title when the user long press the item, as it does for standard action buttons.

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/widget_main_button"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="main"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/widget_login_button"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="login"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/location"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/widget_location_button"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="location"/>
</menu>
```

widget_main_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageButton
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/menu_main_button"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/action_button_width"
    android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_main_menu"/>
```

[image]

---

A useful tool when styling android application is the [Android Resource Navigator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-resource-navigator/) by Jeff Gilfelt. This is a Chrome extension which allows you to quickly navigate the default Android themes and styles to find what you need to change.

Comment: not the ActionButton, but the ACtionBar.  Same concept should work, but when I changed it to android.Widget.ActionBar is has no effect. I even tried setting the bottom padding to negative and got the same bottom pad

Comment: You cannot get rid of the padding at the top and bottom of the of the action items because the [maximum size of the icon is set to **32dp**](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/view/menu/ActionMenuItemView.java#L52), whereas the action bar size is usually set to **48dp**. If your icons height are 32dp or less however, you can set the action bar size to 32dp and get the desired effect

Comment: Since this is an app that is targeting tablets only this size must remain 48x48.    If you design your elements to be at least 48dp high and wide you can guarantee that:

your targets will never be smaller than the minimum recommended target size of 7mm regardless of what screen they are displayed on. (ref: http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html)

Comment: Found another way using actionLayout, which works with 48dp dimensions. And you are right, 32dp **might** be acceptable for phone, but it's a bit risky for a bigger screen. Spacing between elements is equally important though.